# 2 windows while using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Recently while using Unity version 2020.1.11 the taskbar in Windows will show 2 windows and 1 is just a blank background unless you use something like the color dropper or the alignment button. In those cases it will have that portion of the UI in the window with the blank background. Very weird.

If you've solved this please share how to fix it.

Thanks.

Edit notes:

Adding some screenshots and it might help to note that I'm on a shared Unity project with many branches.

[image: img 1]

[image: img 2]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: ![image when using eyedropper](https://res.cloudinary.com/dhzg3horj/image/upload/v1605821083/errors/UnityUI-Errors1_iisqsd.png)

Comment: ![image of thumbnail of 2 windows](https://res.cloudinary.com/dhzg3horj/image/upload/v1605821083/errors/UnityUI-Errors2_mnd9r4.png)

Comment: Also to note that changing the Layout in the top right temporarily fixes this but it comes back at some point. Might be something changing in someone's branch that we don't see. One of us is on a Mac and the other's are on Windows.